# Set Algebra Associativity Over Equal Priority Operations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

qq, does associativity stands with equal precedence operations? Take the following derivation as an example:

$A-\left(B-C\right)=\left(A-B\right)\cup C$

Derivation:

$1.\,A-\left(B-C\right) \;given\\2.\,A\cap\overline{\left(B-C\right)}\; identity\\3.\,A\cap\overline{\left(B\cap \bar{C}\right)}\; identity\\4.\,A\cap\left(\bar{B}\cup C\right) \;De\,morgan\,Law\\5.\, \left(A\cap\bar{B}\right)\cup C\; Associative\,Law\\6.\,\left(A-B\right)\cup C\,identity$

Does the step #5 is valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Associativity is a property of a single operator, e.g., for $\cap$ it says:

$$X \cap (Y \cap Z) = (X \cap Y) \cap Z$$

It is not true that $X \cap (Y \cup Z) = (X \cap Y) \cup Z$ in general, e.g., consider any example in which $X$ is empty but $Z$ is not.

To move on from your line 4 you need to use distributivity.

Comment: >.< ups! Rookie mistake, thanks for the answer